# A folder structure that follow enterprise design patterns

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, vs-code, developer, design-patterns

I come from ASP.net background and I used to have a standardized folder structure such as [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a8024d/best-practices-coding-standards-folder-structure-for-asp/).

I just jumped on a huge project with a lot of custom code. I'm sick of having to scroll through thousands of files under the /classes folder to find what I'm looking for. I'm hoping someone can share a good folder structure to make life easier. Our project follows the "[Apex Enterprise Patterns: Service, Domain, Selecto](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common)r", and of course, we also have controllers, APIs, and some other confusing files that I'm unsure about yet.

I understand that the application needs to be in [force:source format](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sfdx_app_dev/sfdx_app_dev_deploy) to be able to create folder structures under the /main folder. Is there any standardized documentation on how this structure should be set up? Or has anyone come up with a nice design for this? I have already seen the [SFDX-Falcon](https://github.com/sfdx-isv/sfdx-falcon-template) project and gained some info regarding Enterprise pattern structuring, but it doesn't cover controllers, test classes, APIs, and so on.

I'll like the structure to cover the following key elements.

- Enterprise Pattern
- Controllers
- test classes
- APIs
- Outcalls

Thanks,
Nino Y.